# How to add data dynamically to primevue Line chart from vuejs3?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, primevue

I am trying to make a realtime chart with primevue Line Chart as described here:

https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/chart/line

At first I declared the Chart tag with data and options attributes:

```html
<Chart type="line" :data="basicData" :options="basicOptions"/>
```

Then I declared the objects inside data return script:

```js
import Chart from 'primevue/chart'

export default {
  name: 'Chart Test',
  components: {
    Chart
  },
  data () {
    return {
      basicData: {
        labels: ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Speed',
            data: [0],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#42A5F5',
            tension: 0
          }
        ]
      },
      basicOptions: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              color: '#495057'
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057'
            },
            grid: {
              color: '#ebedef'
            }
          },
          y: {
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057'
            },
            grid: {
              color: '#ebedef'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And now I want to add data dynamically, by calling a method like:

```js
    methods: {
        addData () {
            // update data from Chart here dynamically
        }
    }
```

How can I do that? I didn't find this information anywhere on the internet.

**UPDATE**: The accepted answer solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Chart.js docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/developers/updates.html#adding-or-removing-data) indicate that you can push new data into the chart's `data.datasets[]` and `data.labels` properties, and then calling `chart.update()`:

```js
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

PrimeVue's `Chart` component exposes the underlying [Chart.js instance via `chart`](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/6283255/src/components/chart/Chart.vue#L54), so you can use that property update the chart:

1. Apply a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs) on the `Chart` component:

   ```html
   <Chart ref="primeChart">
   ```

   ```js
   import { ref } from 'vue'

   export default {
     setup() {
       const primeChart = ref()
       // chart.js instance is now available via primeChart.value.chart

       return {
         primeChart,
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Return the chart data from `setup()` (i.e., use the Composition API to avoid making the bound array data reactive). *This is necessary to avoid a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error when modifying the chart data.*

   ```js
   export default {
     setup() {
       return {
         // non-reactive data
         basicData: {/*...*/},
         basicOptions: {/*...*/},
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create an `addData` method that updates the chart.js instance (via the template ref), following the example from the Chart.js docs above:

   ```js
   export default {
     setup() {
       const primeChart = ref()

       const addData = () => {
         const chart = primeChart.value.chart
         chart.data.labels.push(/* NEW DATA LABEL */)
         chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(/* NEW DATA VALUE */)
         chart.update()
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Now you can use `addData()` (e.g., through a button click) to update the chart with new data.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-primevue-add-data-to-linechart?file=src/App.vue)