# VueJS template ref causes recursive updates

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, primevue

I'm trying to use the PrimeVue [Chart](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/chart) component in my VueJS app, but to do that I need to reference the underlying chart, which requires a [template reference](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html). Unfortunately, as soon as I add that, I get "Maximum recursive updates exceeded." Here's a super-simple component that causes it:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue"

const pvChart = ref(null)

let basicData =  {
        datasets: [{
                label: "Setpoints",
                data: [{ x: -10, y: 0 },
                        { x: 0, y: 10 },
                        { x: 10, y: 5 },
                        { x: 0.5, y: 5.5 }],
                showLine: true,
            },
        ]
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card">
            <pv-chart ref="pvChart" type="scatter" :data="basicData" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I don't even try to update anything (AFAICT).

I tried to follow the example in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049978/how-to-add-data-dynamically-to-primevue-line-chart-from-vuejs3), but it's written in a slightly different style, and I'm not sure I didn't miss something in the translation.

**Update:**

Changing the name of the ref from `pvChart` to `primeChart` fixes all the issues. I just grepped my whole codebase and there is no other `pvChart` in it anywhere. I don’t know why this is an issue.

Comment: Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. The snippet is ok and shouldn't cause a recursion

Comment: So I just discovered the problem. The specific name `pvChart` causes the problem. I changed it to `primeChart` and now all is okay. I don't have `pvChart` anywhere else in my code, so I don’t know why. I do have `pv-chart`.